# Disabling the rotation on a tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

My app has rotation enabled for mobiles but I don't want landscape mode in tablet.

I have tried

```
<activity 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

but this does't specify portrait mode for tablets only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need to do it programmatically, I don't think is any property for the manifest to set it up.

**First step** detect app installed in a tablet, something like this:

**Java:**

```
 public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);
        boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        return (xlarge || large);
    }
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun isTablet(context: Context): Boolean {
        val xlarge = context.resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK === Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
        val large =
            context.resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK === Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
        return xlarge || large
    }
```

**Kotlin extension:**

```
    fun Context.isTablet(): Boolean {
        val xlarge = resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK === Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
        val large =
            resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK === Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
        return xlarge || large
    }
```

**Second step**, change it in onCreate:

**Java**

```
if(isTablet(this)){
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

**Kotlin extension**

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(isTablet()){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seriously, I never thought of it, thanks a lot. @Miguel

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up from code but you can also have it in XML file only, but the trick is to use [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) and either have separate XML for what you call tablet or have separate style for tablets and apply that style to the activity.

Comment: but even if i have only portrait layout, still my app rotates on tablet. thanks